# which is best api in java for data migration between db to db

Tags: java, sql-server, database, api, database-migration

I need to transfer data from Ms SQl server to another same db on another server, Can anyone please suggest me any tool or api that can be integrated in java so that I configure both the db, destination and start up db and it works like that.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need to midify some data look into

http://www.talend.com/products/data-integration

If you just want a identical copy of your database just create a backup and copy this to the other server.

See for some explenations:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187510.aspx